# Merge difference of two tables in third table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table1 and Table2 with such data
[image]

[image]

Re highlighted,there is an additional data field in `Table2`. 
 and I want a resultant table like this
[image]

as three highlighted area shows that if there is something which is not present in any one of the table then it will be displayed as null in resultant table.
I have tried different solutions using `except` and different `joins` but didn't work. Please suggest some solution.Thanks

Comment: `left/full` join will do the thing

Comment: can you please share the query :)

Comment: Share the query that did not work to review errors if any. It is strange if you tried `outer` joins and did not succeed. Probably you missed something in task description because right now there is absolutely nothing complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date]),
       CASE 
          WHEN t1.[Group] IS NULL OR t2.[Group] IS NULL THEN NULL
          ELSE t1.[Group]
       END
FROM Table1 AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
  ON t1.[date] = t2.[date] AND t1.[Group] = t2.[Group]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Full outer join** is the answer, additionally I would add a third column displaying in which table has the data.

```
select isnull(t1.[Date],t2.[Date]) [Date],
       isnull(t1.[Group], t2.[Group])   [Group],
       case 
            when t1.[Date] is null then 'Only on table 2'
            when t2.[Date] is null then 'Only on table 1'
            else 'On both tables'
        end 
from table1 as t1
full outer join Table2 as t2 
    on t1.[Date] = t2.[Date] AND t1.[Group] = t2.[Group]
```